# Spring Boot controller - Upload Multipart and JSON to DTO

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I want to upload a file inside a form to a Spring Boot API endpoint.

The UI is written in React:

```
export function createExpense(formData) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post(ENDPOINT,
      formData, 
      headers: {
        'Authorization': //...,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      ).then(({data}) => {
        //...
      })
      .catch(({response}) => {
        //...
      });
    };
}

  _onSubmit = values => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', values.title);
    formData.append('description', values.description);
    formData.append('amount', values.amount);
    formData.append('image', values.image[0]);
    this.props.createExpense(formData);
  }
```

This is the java side code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{groupId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ExpenseSnippetGetDto create(@RequestBody ExpensePostDto expenseDto, @PathVariable long groupId, Principal principal, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
   //..
}
```

But I get this exception on the Java side:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryapHVvBsdZYc6j4Af;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

How should I resolve this issue? The similar API endpoints and JavaScript side code is already working.

#### Note

I've seen a solution where it suggests that the request body should have 2 attributes: one which the JSON section goes under, another for the image. I'd like to see if it is possible to have it automatically converted to DTO.

---

### Update 1

The upload payload sent by the client should be converted to the following DTO:

```
public class ExpensePostDto extends ExpenseBaseDto {

    private MultipartFile image;

    private String description;

    private List<Long> sharers;

}
```

So you can say it's a mix of JSON and *multipart*.

---

### Solution

The solution to the problem is to use `FormData` on the front-end and `ModelAttribute` on the backend:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{groupId}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public ExpenseSnippetGetDto create(@ModelAttribute ExpensePostDto expenseDto, @PathVariable long groupId, Principal principal) throws IOException {
   //...
}
```

and on the front-end, get rid of `Content-Type` as it should be determined by the browser itself, and use `FormData` (standard JavaScript). That should solve the problem.

Comment: Your content type is incorrect, FormData does not produce `application/json`

Comment: I changed it to `multipart/form-data` and I still get the same error.

Comment: This is what you exactly need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699727/multipart-file-upload-spring-boot?rq=1

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Yes, you can simply do it via wrapper class.

1) Create a `Class` to hold form data:

```
public class FormWrapper {
    private MultipartFile image;
    private String title;
    private String description;
}
```

2) Create an HTML `form` for submitting data:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm" action="link">
    <input type="text" name="title"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="description"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="image"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
```

3) Create a method to receive form's `text` data and `multipart` file:

```
@PostMapping("/api/upload/multi/model")
public ResponseEntity<?> multiUploadFileModel(@ModelAttribute FormWrapper model) {
    try {
        // Save as you want as per requiremens
        saveUploadedFile(model.getImage());
        formRepo.save(mode.getTitle(), model.getDescription());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity("Successfully uploaded!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

4) Method to save `file`:

```
private void saveUploadedFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to get utf-8 characters if I passed here in "title" variable. Because currently, I'm getting ???? for this. English characters are working fine.

Comment: @VijayShegokar did you add `CharacterEncodingFilter` in `web.xml`?

Comment: yes. Actually there two applications. First application forwarding the request to another application via Zuul Proxy. I'm also getting the title, description these values as duplicate(comma separated) in the second application controller. But If I copy paste the same code in First application Controller and access that then everything works fine.

Comment: I think you should create a separate question for it so people can understand the problem. Or if you can find similar questions then please tag me in.

Comment: When I do this, all fields in "model" come up null. @ModelAttribute is somehow not able to map the form fields to the DTO fields

Comment: Just figured out my problem! My DTO had no getters and setters (all fields were public). For some reason, the fields will not be mapped to the DTO if getters and setters are absent. When I added the getters and setters, I was now able to receive the form fields in the DTO

Comment: Yes setters are required, spring use them for mapping. If you are using immutable objects then you neend to write custom WebArgumentResolver.

Comment: how to test this via postman

Comment: I consider the solution below much better because it is not necessary to use a DTO on the server.

Answer (score 46):

I had created a similar thing using pure JS and Spring Boot.
Here is the [Repo.](https://github.com/GSSwain/file-upload-ajax-sample)
I'm sending an `User` object as `JSON` and a `File` as part of the `multipart/form-data` request.

The relevant snippets are below

The `Controller` code

```
@RestController
public class FileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    public void upload(@RequestPart("user") @Valid User user,
            @RequestPart("file") @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile file) {
            System.out.println(user);
            System.out.println("Uploaded File: ");
            System.out.println("Name : " + file.getName());
            System.out.println("Type : " + file.getContentType());
            System.out.println("Name : " + file.getOriginalFilename());
            System.out.println("Size : " + file.getSize());
    }

    static class User {
        @NotNull
        String firstName;
        @NotNull
        String lastName;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
        }

    }
}
```

The `HTML` and `JS` code

```
<html>    
<head>
    <script>
        function onSubmit() {

            var formData = new FormData();

            formData.append("file", document.forms["userForm"].file.files[0]);
            formData.append('user', new Blob([JSON.stringify({
                "firstName": document.getElementById("firstName").value,
                "lastName": document.getElementById("lastName").value
            })], {
                    type: "application/json"
                }));
            var boundary = Math.random().toString().substr(2);
            fetch('/upload', {
                method: 'post',
                body: formData
            }).then(function (response) {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    alert("There was an error!");
                } else {
                    alert("Request successful");
                }
            }).catch(function (err) {
                alert("There was an error!");
            });;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="userForm">
        <label> File : </label>
        <br/>
        <input name="file" type="file">
        <br/>
        <label> First Name : </label>
        <br/>
        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" />
        <br/>
        <label> Last Name : </label>
        <br/>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" />
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="onSubmit(); return false;" />
    </form>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: It worked for me. Just adding, it was necessary to add: processData: false, contentType: false, cache: false, so that it works well. Spring Boot 2.1.7. 
and it was not necessary to add the "consumes".

Comment: @GSSwain it working fine for me. How to test the endpoint from POSTMAN.

Comment: Somebody got it to work in Postman?

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar use case where I had some JSON data and image upload (Think of it as a user trying to register with a personal details and profile image).

Referring to @Stephan and @GSSwain answer I came up with a solution with Spring Boot and AngularJs.

Below is a snapshot of my code. Hope it helps someone.

```
    var url = "https://abcd.com/upload";
    var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }

    }
    var data = {
        name: $scope.name,
        email: $scope.email
    }
    $scope.fd.append("obj", new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
                type: "application/json"
            }));

    $http.post(
        url, $scope.fd,config
    )
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("success", response)
            // This function handles success

        }, function (response) {
            console.log("error", response)
            // this function handles error

        });
```

And SpringBoot controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {   "multipart/form-data" })
@ResponseBody
public boolean uploadImage(@RequestPart("obj") YourDTO dto, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // your logic
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I built my most recent file upload application in AngularJS and SpringBoot which are similar enough in syntax to help you here.

My client side request handler:

```
uploadFile=function(fileData){
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('file',fileData);
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/uploadFile',
        data: formData,
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':undefined,
            'Accept':'application/json'
        }
    });
};
```

One thing to note is Angular automatically sets the multipart mime type and boundary on the 'Content-Type' header value for me. Yours may not, in which case you need to set it yourself.

My application expects a JSON response from the server, thus the 'Accept' header.

You are passing in the FormData object yourself, so you need to make sure that your form is setting the File to whatever attribute you map to on your Controller. In my case it is mapped to the 'file' parameter on the FormData object.

My controller endpoints look like this:

```
@POST
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
{
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can add as many other @RequestParam as you'd like, including your DTO that represents the rest of the form, just make sure its structured that way as a child of the FormData object.

**The key take-away here is that each @RequestParam is an attribute on the FormData object body payload on the multipart request.**

If I were to modify my code to accommodate your data, it would look something like this:

```
uploadFile=function(fileData, otherData){
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('file',fileData);
    formData.append('expenseDto',otherData);
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/uploadFile',
        data: formData,
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':undefined,
            'Accept':'application/json'
        }
    });
};
```

Then your controller endpoint would look like this:

```
@POST
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("expenseDto") ExpensePostDto expenseDto)
{
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Your endpoint takes only one param, which is `file` and of type multipart form data. Mine is a combinatio of json and multipart. I update my post to include the DTO.

Comment: You can't do that. If you look at a pure multipart packet, the body is reserved for the file data. You're allowed to put path parameters, but not additional body payloads. I should have noticed that when I answered. I'll correct my answer when I'm off mobile.

Comment: What is this example on Axios github then: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html

Comment: They're doing exactly what I have in the example above with the formData.append(). I think you're misunderstanding how the packet gets built behind the scenes. If you have a running copy of their example, I suggest you watch the network traffic in chrome and look at the packet structure.

Comment: how to populate `otherData` of `formData.append('expenseDto',otherData);`? I tried `var otherData = {'name':'a'}`, but it throws error `Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'ExpenseDto'`.

Comment: does your `ExpenseDTO` object have one attribute `name`, and no other required attributes? Spring automatically tries to deserialize the payload into a POJO assuming the POJO contains and is annotated to be valid from the JSON provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/test" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
@ResponseBody
public String create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam String description, @RequestParam ArrayList<Long> sharers) throws Exception {
    ExpensePostDto expensePostDto = new ExpensePostDto(file, description, sharers);
    // do your thing
    return "test";
}
```

This seems to be the easiest way out here, other ways could be to add your own messageConverter.

Answer (score 1):

```
@PostMapping( path = "/upload")
public ResponseEntity uploadRT14(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestPart("uploadedFileInfo") UploadFileDTO uploadFileDTO) {
       ....... 
    }
```

i needed to send a file and json reqBody both at the same time, I tried using `@RequestBody` for `UploadFileDTO` but didn't work. also tried using `@RequestParam` that also didn't work as the dto was not a string, it was json. Finally it worked using `@RequestPart`

below is the postman setting that i used to test
[image]

Answer (score 1):

this is how i implemented it.

in frontend - angular

> // there is a sample model used to show the concept of sending
> files and model in same HTTP request
> this is the model class in Angular

```
class ReportRequestModel {
constructor(public appName: string, public version: string) {}
}
```

> angular app.component.ts code

```
onUpload() {

const model = new ReportRequestModel('o support', '2.0');

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', this.selectedFile);
formData.append('dto', JSON.stringify(model));

this.http
  .post('http://localhost:8088/', formData, {
    observe: 'response',
  })
  .subscribe((response) => {
    this.getImageNames();
  });
```

> in java-spring API i used ObjectMapper to deserialize the String dto to
> Java class ReportRequestDTO

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Report> saveReport(@RequestBody List<MultipartFile> files, 
                                         @RequestPart String dto){
    
    
    try {
      var data = objectMapper.readValue(dto, ReportRequestDTO.class);
      System.out.println(data);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    Report savedReport = null;
    
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
    
    Report report = null;       
    
    try {
        report = new Report();
        report.setFileData(file.getBytes());
        report.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        report.setFileContent(file.getContentType());
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    
    
    
    try {
        savedReport = reportsRepository.save(report);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }       
    
    }
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(savedReport);
}
```

> ReportRequestDTO class

```
@Data
public class ReportRequestDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@JsonProperty("appName")
private String appName;

@JsonProperty("version")
private String version;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell spring you're consuming `multipart/form-data` by adding `consumes = "multipart/form-data"` to the `RequestMapping` annotation.  Also remove the `RequestBody` annotation from the `expenseDto` parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{groupId}", consumes = "multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ExpenseSnippetGetDto create(ExpensePostDto expenseDto, 
   @PathVariable long groupId, Principal principal, BindingResult result) 
   throws IOException {
   //..
}
```

With the posted `ExpensePostDto` the `title` in the request is ignored.

**Edit**

You'll also need to change the content type to `multipart/form-data`.  Sounds like that's the default for `post` based on some other answers.  Just to be safe, I would specify it:

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from the react front end:

```
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Modify the Java side controller:

```
   @PostMapping("/{groupId}")
   public Expense create(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image,  @RequestParam("amount") double amount, @RequestParam("description") String description, @RequestParam("title") String title) throws IOException {
         //storageService.store(file); ....
          //String imagePath = path.to.stored.image;
         return new Expense(amount, title, description, imagePath);
 }
```

This can be written better but tried keeping it as close to your original code as much as I could. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the DTO class having public fields and not getter/setter methods

```
public class MyDTO {
    public MultipartFile[] files;
    public String user;
    public String text;
}
```

The DTO class MUST have getters/setters, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

it took me the whole morning to find out the answer

I am doing form upload images and content using NextJS and Spring boot

```
 @PostMapping(consumes = {   "multipart/form-data" })
    @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
    public Object createProduct(@RequestPart("product")  ProductDTO product,
        @RequestParam(value = "primaryImage", required = false) MultipartFile mainImageMultipart,
        @RequestParam(value = "extraImage", required = false) MultipartFile[] extraImageMultiparts
                                ) throws ParseException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(productServiceImpl.createOne(product, mainImageMultipart,extraImageMultiparts ));

    }
```

and in nextjs api route

```
async function products(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { token } = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie);

    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const form = formidable();

      form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) reject({ err });
        resolve({ err, fields, files });
      });
    });

    const { err, fields, files } = data;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
      "product",
      new Blob([fields.product[0]], {
        type: "application/json",
      })
    );
    formData.append("primaryImage", getDataFile(files.primaryImage[0]));

    for (let i = 0; i < files.extraImage.length; i++) {
      formData.append("extraImage", getDataFile(files.extraImage[i]));
    }

    const resPost = await fetch(`${API_URL}/products`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: formData,
    });

    const dataPos = await resPost.json();

    if (!resPost.ok) {
      console.log("Loi la " + JSON.stringify(dataPos));
      res.status(500).json({ message: dataPos.message });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ products: dataPos });
    }
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Data processed successfully" });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the consumer type to your request mapping .it should  work fine.

```
@POST
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,consumes = "multipart/form-data") 
{
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```