# Spring boot controller - Upload Multipart file and Java Object,Angular 4,7

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, multipart

how to send data using Postman in example DTO ,mainly Multipart file data,Angular 4,7

data in Multipartfile in Example DTO

```
public class ExampleDTo {

    private MultipartFile image;

    private String name;
    private String description;

}
```

Controller Mapping

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<?> saveExample(@RequestParam("dtoAnduploadingFiles") ExampleDTo  dtoAnduploadingFiles  ) throws IOException {

}
```

Comment: Hi Myjaysan in angular if uploading file its not work  with same code you have to be handle few more things in angular  if you  know that good if you dont please reply me

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use multiple multiparts.

So for example if you use this controller:

```
@PostMapping
public void uploadFileWithData(
        @RequestPart ExampleDTo request,
        @RequestPart("file") final MultipartFile file){
    ...
}
```

note: ExampleDto should contain only fields of json payload, not MultipartFile

In Postman you should use then form-data and choose file which you want to upload and also file with json payload.
[image: postman]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like a normal multipart `Form` from Postman but you need to update your `Mapping Method`.

```
@PostMapping("/upload-file-form")
    public ResponseEntity<?> multiUploadFileModel(@ModelAttribute ExampleDTo model) {
        try {
            saveUploadedFile(model.getImage()); // Create method to save your file or just do it here
            formRepo.save(mode.getName(),model.getDescription()); //Save as per requirement 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity("Successfully uploaded!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

For complete code example look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991403/4704510).
And then you can test it on postman like this:
[image]