# multipart/form-data MutlipartFile is not set through all args constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

### Background

The problem came up on my day job while implementing a `POST multipart/form-data` endpoint for a file upload with some meta information. I am not an expert in the Spring Boot ecosystem; it is likely that the problem is solved by a simple fix and that I am just missing the right term to search for.

### Problem statement

To implement an endpoint for a file-upload with additional meta information, I wrote the following `@RestController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Resource.ROOT)
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject}))
public class Resource {
  public static final String ROOT = "/test";

  private final Logger logger;

  @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public ResponseEntity<Void> test(@Valid final Request request) {
    logger.info("request = {}", request);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
}
```

With `Request` being specified as:

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Request {

  @NotNull
  String name;

  @NotNull
  MultipartFile file;
}
```

And a small happy path test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class TestCase {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  void shouldReturnOk() throws Exception {
    // GIVEN
    final byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(".", "src/test/resources/PenPen.png"));
    final String name = "name";

    // WHEN
    // @formatter:off
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .multipart(Resource.ROOT)
            .file("file", content)
            .param("name", name))

    // THEN
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    // @formatter:on
  }
}
```

A complete MRE can be found on [Bitbucket, branch `problem-with-immutable-request`](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/springboot-multipart-formdata-fileupload/src/problem-with-immutable-request/).

When running the test (`./mvnw test)`, it fails with the endpoint returning a `400 BAD REQUEST` instead of `200 OK`. Reading the logs reveals that request parameter `file` is `null`:

```
...
     Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
             Body = file: must not be null.
...
```

I partially understand why it is `null`. With this partial knowledge, I was able to circumvent the problem by making the field `file` in `Request` mutable:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Request {

  @NotNull
  private final String name;

  @Setter
  @NotNull
  private MultipartFile file;
}
```

The code "fixing" the problem can be found on [Bitbucket, branch `problem-solved-by-making-field-mutable`](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/springboot-multipart-formdata-fileupload/src/problem-solved-by-making-field-mutable/).

This, however, makes the `Request` mutable, which I would like to prevent. To further investigate, I unrolled the lombok annotations on `Request` and added some logging:

```
public class Request {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Request.class);

  @NotNull
  private final String name;

  @NotNull
  private MultipartFile file;

  public Request(final String name, final MultipartFile file) {
    this.name = name;
    this.setFile(file);
  }

  public @NotNull String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public @NotNull MultipartFile getFile() {
    return this.file;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Request(name=" + this.getName() + ", file=" + this.getFile() + ")";
  }

  public void setFile(final MultipartFile file) {
    LOGGER.info("file = {}", file);
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

Code of unrolled version can be found on [Bitbucket, branch `lombok-unrolled-for-debugging`](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/springboot-multipart-formdata-fileupload/src/lombok-unrolled-for-debugging/).

When looking at the log statements of the now successful test, we can see that `Request::setFile` is called twice:

```
2020-09-05 09:42:31.049  INFO 11012 --- [           main] d.turing85.springboot.multipart.Request  : file = null
2020-09-05 09:42:31.056  INFO 11012 --- [           main] d.turing85.springboot.multipart.Request  : file = org.springframework.mock.web
```

The first call comes from the constructor invocation. The second call, I imagine, comes from somewhere within Spring's mapping mechanism for the form parameters.

I know that there is the possibility to define the form parameters individually on the endpoint and constructing the `Request` instance within the method:

```
public class Resource {
  ...
  @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public ResponseEntity<Void> test(
      @RequestPart(name = "name") final String name,
      @RequestPart(name = "file") final MultipartFile file) {
    final Request request = new Request(name, file);
    logger.info("request = {}", request);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
}
```

This will, however, result in other problems. For example, we would have to add an additional exception mapper for `MissingServletRequestPartException` and align the returned HTTP response with the existing response for `BindException`. I would like to avoid this if possible.

A search on the topic turned up [Spring Boot controller - Upload Multipart and JSON to DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845355/spring-boot-controller-upload-multipart-and-json-to-dto). The solution, however, did not work for me since I do not use MVC (I think).

### Question

Is there a possibility to keep `Request` immutable such that Spring is able to pass the `MultipartFile` to the all args constructor instead of setting it through the setter afterwards? Writing a custom mapper/converter is acceptable, but I did not find a possibility to write a mapper for either a specific endpoint or a specific type.

Comment: is it necessary to wrap the `MultipartFile`? seems like if you will separate it you will have no mutability problems

Comment: I tried with ModelAttribute and it works but you have to define setter for multipart data else it will be null.

Comment: @limido Yes, it is. I gave an explanation as to why I want it to be in `Request` in my post.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez defining setters defeats the point. I have already demonstrated that providing a setter for `file` "fixes" the problem, without adding `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: Ofcourse it defeats the point but converter is using setter to convert multipart file data

Answer (score 0):

```
 @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<Void> test(@Valid @ModelAttribute final RequestDto request) {
     return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
 }
```

It is still working with rest api call. But i really do not get immutability concern of yours.

If you define setter the multipart data you can use ModelAttribute.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class FileUploadControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnOk() throws Exception {
        // GIVEN
        final byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("text.txt").toURI()));
        final String name = "name";

        // WHEN
        // @formatter:off
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .multipart("/context/api/v1")
                .file("multipartFile", content)
                .param("name", name))

                // THEN
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

The above code works with ModelAttribute.

Also you are giving absolute path, i guess it is wrong. You can get file with classloader.

Comment: For me, the test still fails with `@ModelAttriibute`. This does not answer the question. As to why I want immutability: with JSON requests, we have the possibility to annotate the DTO such that a bulder is used. For form data, this seems to not be the case. This in return leads to a heterogenus structure of DTOs, which in return introduces unnecessary complexity.