# How to send POST request with mutltipart file as embedded parameter

Tags: spring, rest, postman, soapui, multipartfile

I have a WrapperDTO which has FileDTO which has file parameter which is file ( pdf, txt, csv). I want to send this to a Rest service. My service layer is implemented in Spring. ( I followed this article [Spring ModelAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845355/spring-boot-controller-upload-multipart-and-json-to-dto). I want to test this and not able to create request in SOAP UI or POSTMAN. Please guide or suggest other way to achieve this. My requirement is to send staffdata, filedata and file together in one request.

```
{
   "staffName": "ABC",
   "staffrole" : "CDE",
   "keyfile": {
        "filecode": "XYZ",
         "file" : "Multipart file -- PDF, TXT, CSV"     
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add considerably more substance to this question; as it's written, we can only assume what your model and controller look like or the values that you're trying to send in the field, `file`.  If it's a `MultipartFile`, it needs to be an object in your JSON, not just a String.