# How to Send Axios Multipart File with JSON Body to Springboot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, rest, axios, multipartform-data

I am working on a react native project, which is leveraging Axios, that hits our Springboot backend.

We have a support endpoint that looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> sendSupportRequest(@Valid @RequestPart ContactRequest request,
@Valid @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile[] files) {
```

where ContactRequest is the Json object and files is the multipart.

Our call from the frontend using axios looks like this:

```
const form = new FormData();
  form.append('request', new Blob([JSON.stringify({
    id: data.id,
    subject: data.subject,
    description: data.description,
})], {
        type: "application/json"
    }));

  return axiosClient.post("/support", form, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type":
        'multipart/form-data',
    },
  });
```

I have added an axios request interceptor that outputs this on a request:

`{"adapter": ["xhr", "http"], "baseURL": "http://localhost:8080", "data": {"_parts": [[Array]]}, "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "post", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "/support", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}`

I have also set logging level to TRACE and get incoming request for our endpoint:

```
2023-11-18 14:41:41 2023-11-18T21:41:41.662Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [POST /support HTTP/1.1
2023-11-18 14:41:41 Host: localhost:8080
2023-11-18 14:41:41 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=4xEz1d1nsHJOHNY2u6sjIEP3r_NSLnRUtkltGdUFEc4v4BS0J4.DyJ--48c8-7f2SK4ysv
2023-11-18 14:41:41 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2023-11-18 14:41:41 User-Agent: Expo/2.29.6 CFNetwork/1474 Darwin/23.0.0
2023-11-18 14:41:41 Connection: keep-alive
2023-11-18 14:41:41 baggage: sentry-environment=qa,sentry-public_key=123,sentry-trace_id=456
2023-11-18 14:41:41 Accept: application/json
2023-11-18 14:41:41 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
2023-11-18 14:41:41 Authorization: Bearer abc.123
2023-11-18 14:41:41 Content-Length: 234
2023-11-18 14:41:41 sentry-trace: xxx-xxx
2023-11-18 14:41:41 
2023-11-18 14:41:41 --4xEz1d1nsHJOHNY2u6sjIEP3r_NSLnRUtkltGdUFEc4v4BS0J4.DyJ--48c8-7f2SK4ysv
2023-11-18 14:41:41 content-disposition: form-data; name="request"
2023-11-18 14:41:41 content-type: application/json
2023-11-18 14:41:41 
2023-11-18 14:41:41 
2023-11-18 14:41:41 --4xEz1d1nsHJOHNY2u6sjIEP3r_NSLnRUtkltGdUFEc4v4BS0J4.DyJ--48c8-7f2SK4ysv--
2023-11-18 14:41:41 ]
2023-11-18 14:41:41 2023-11-18T21:41:41.666Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request POST /support
2023-11-18 14:41:41 2023-11-18T21:41:41.667Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2023-11-18 14:41:41 2023-11-18T21:41:41.668Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2023-11-18 14:41:41 2023-11-18T21:41:41.668Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning instance
```

As you can see, it gets the content-disposition correctly, but there is no body

I have tried following the axios docs [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart) with no luck.

I also stumbled across this stack overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49993072) but was unsuccessful.

Our Insomnia requests work correctly as shown below:
[image].

I have tried removing our consumes tag from the endpoint with also no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this for a few days now.

Comment: Did you check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845355/spring-boot-controller-upload-multipart-and-json-to-dto