# How to send a Image from Angularjs to Spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to send an object with an image from angular but I got the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

When I set just the MultiprtFile as parameter and I send with angular just the file it works!! but I need to do that with the object but I keep getting the error but I don't know why

My entity class DTO is this:

```
 @Data
public class PersonRequest {
    private String id;
    private Integer personId;
    private String name;
    private String job1;
    private String job2;
    private String skills;
   // private Binary image;
    private String country;
    private String imageString;

}
```

this is my controller:

```
 @PostMapping("multi")
public String multi(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, @RequestBody PersonRequest personRequest) throws IOException {
    Binary files = new Binary(file.getBytes());
    log.info("file: {}, personRequest: {}",file, personRequest);
```

My code in html is this:

```
 <h5>Upload Image</h5>
        <p-fileUpload  mode="basic" #imageInput  (change)="processFile(imageInput)"
                 [showUploadButton]="false" [showCancelButton]="false" accept="image/*"
                      chooseLabel="Choose File"></p-fileUpload>
```

in my ts:

```
processFile(imageInput: any) {
    this.file=imageInput.files[0];
}
```

and this in my service:

```
addPersonWithIMG(image:File,personRequest: PersonRequest):Observable<any>{
    const HttpUploadOptions = {
//commented this because it won't work
    //  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" })
    }
    const file: FormData = new FormData();
    file.append('file', image);
    return this.http.post<PersonRequest>(`${this.baseUrl+"multi"}`,{file,personRequest});
  }
```

In my entity I will save the image as Binary object, when I send just the file from angular it works but when I trying to add the object in the request I got that exception.

Please can anybody help me

Comment: your controller is expecting a MultipartFile, but it seems you are sending a single normal fileµ

Comment: @Stultuske when in my controller I set as parameter just MultipartFile, it works! the problem is when I add an object, anyway I woud like to add in the object field but it won't work anyway, do you have any idea?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33921749/4355748

Comment: @Rana_S I got this error when I add to the append method the object personReqeust:
TS2345: Argument of type 'PersonRequest' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'

Maybe there is any other way to add the file in the field of the object? I tried to but I still get exceptions

Comment: Basically, you use `FormData` to send file as well as other params to the server. In your controller, use the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` to access the file and params.